# How to read a CSV file line by line and write to another CSV file. How to skip the first 4 rows while writing to another file using C#?

Tags: c#, csv

I am totally new to C#, I want to read a CSV file line by line and write to another CSV file while writing I need to skip the first 4 lines, Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code I tried.

```
int index = 0;
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("D:\\work\\POCs\\POC_RESOURCES\\Pricing_Files\\index-edited-ap-east-1.csv")))

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("D:\\work\\POCs\\SPOT_POC_RESOURCES\\Pricing_Files\\index-ap-east-1.csv")))
                {

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine(index);
                                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                                writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                }
```

Comment: You should only read a line once per loop cycle

Comment: You've got an endless loop because you're not reading any lines except where `index > 4`, and you're also only incrementing `index` _inside_ the body of the if statement, meaning that it will never be incremented with your current implementation.

Comment: Also, don't do this: `Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());`. Assign the line read to a local variable, then show it in the Console and write it, otherwise you're skipping lines. Avoid hard-coded paths.

Comment: I just changed the code, it writes all the lines to the writer file, can anyone please tell how to skip the first 4 rows while writing?

Comment: you have to call `write.Flush()` to save all the data in the stream memory to persist in the file.

Comment: You have to read a line on every loop-cycle not only the ones that should be writen into the other file

Comment: @Ackdari I applied the suggestions given, It is currently writing all the lines to the writer file but I want to skip the first 4 rows while writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Skip the first 4 lines of the input file you need to read a line on every iteration of the `while` loop

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("D:\\work\\POCs\\POC_RESOURCES\\Pricing_Files\\index-edited-ap-east-1.csv")))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("D:\\work\\POCs\\SPOT_POC_RESOURCES\\Pricing_Files\\index-ap-east-1.csv")))
{
    var index = 0;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (index > 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it now skips the first 4 rows and writes to another file